# JLabel display too short for the whole text

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

This is an example of JLabel displayed too short and has not enough space for the "website" (refer to the code) part.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JLabeleg extends JFrame
{
public JLabeleg()
{
    setTitle("Example");
    setSize(500,100);
    setVisible(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    Container eg = getContentPane();
    JPanel west = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
    JPanel center = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,3));

    eg.add(west,BorderLayout.WEST);
    eg.add(center,BorderLayout.CENTER);


    west.add(new JLabel("Name         :  "));
    west.add(new JLabel("Website     :  "));

    center.add(new JLabel("Szekuns"));
    center.add(new JLabel(""));
    center.add(new JLabel(""));
    center.add(new JLabel("www.example.com.my/example/example"));
    center.add(new JLabel(""));
    center.add(new JLabel(""));

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JLabeleg example = new JLabeleg();
    example.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

What is different between my original code and this example is that the source of JLabel is actually a "setText" from an Object load from an IO file. Does that matter? Is there anyway for the "www.example.com/example/example" to have a full view? Maybe by taking the space of the JLabel on the right hand side?

Comment: @Guillaume Polet - Szekuns here. This is a SSCCE for my problem about the JLabel. Your advise will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try using `pack` instead of `setSize` only AFTER you have created the UI, also, make `setVisible` the last statement in the constructor

Comment: @MadProgrammer But i wanna fix the size of the window as it display. =(

Comment: So what do want to happen when the label doesn't have room to display the text?  Not every system will use the same font or DPI ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer can i use two JLabel to display one sentence? or I need to use **JTable** or another Layout?

Comment: Can you use a non-editable `JTextArea`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer nope , maybe i should try GridBagLayout?

Comment: If there's not enough space to allow the label to show the text, the problem will remain the space...

Comment: @Szekuns 2 things you can do after setting the text of your `JLabel`'s: 1) call `pack()` on the containing frame (this is likely to cause a resize of your `JFrame` 2) call `revalidate()` on the `center` panel (in this case, the frame won't resize, but if there is enough space for the labels to all display, they will get enough space). Regarding `GridBagLayout` it may be a better layout in your case but it requires more work to set up.

Comment: @MadProgrammer i've choose to use GridBagLayout. It is simple and easy to use. Suitable for beginner like me^^  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to use `pack()` after loading the text of your labels. I don't like much this solution because I find it disturbing for the user.

`GridLayout` will also soon show you some important limitations (if you have one big label and others are quite small, a lot of free space will get lost, since all labels will get the size of the biggest label). In all cases, I would recommend to only set the number of "rows" or the number of "columns" of the `GridLayout`, this is easier to maintain.

`GridBagLayout` might be an alternative but takes a wee bit more experience to master.

Finally, a `JTable` might be a better option in your situation (but we lack the context of what you are trying to achieve).

Here are 2 examples showing how you can get things done (but there are many other possibilities which might be better, explaining your target would help us be more precise).

Example 1 (using `pack()` and `GridLayout`):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JLabeleg extends JFrame {

    private List<JLabel> labels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();

    public JLabeleg() {
        setTitle("Example");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        Container eg = getContentPane();
        JPanel west = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        final JPanel center = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 3));
        JButton load = new JButton("Load labels");
        load.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int i = 0;
                for (JLabel label : labels) {
                    label.setText("A very very very long long long long label " + String.valueOf(++i));
                }
                JLabeleg.this.pack();
                JLabeleg.this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            }
        });
        eg.add(west, BorderLayout.WEST);
        eg.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        eg.add(load, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        west.add(new JLabel("Name         :  "));
        west.add(new JLabel("Website     :  "));

        center.add(new JLabel("Szekuns"));
        center.add(new JLabel(""));
        center.add(new JLabel(""));
        center.add(new JLabel("www.example.com.my/example/example"));
        center.add(new JLabel(""));
        center.add(new JLabel(""));
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel();
            center.add(label);
            labels.add(label);
    }
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new JLabeleg();
        }
    });

}
}
```

Example 2 (using `GridBagLayout` and `revalidate()`)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JLabeleg extends JFrame {

    private List<JLabel> labels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();

    public JLabeleg() {
        setTitle("Example");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container eg = getContentPane();
        JPanel west = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        final JPanel center = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JButton load = new JButton("Load labels");
        load.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int i = 0;
                for (JLabel label : labels) {
                    label.setText("A very long label " + String.valueOf(++i));
                }
                center.revalidate();
            }
        });
        eg.add(west, BorderLayout.WEST);
        eg.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        eg.add(load, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        west.add(new JLabel("Name         :  "));
        west.add(new JLabel("Szekuns"));
        west.add(new JLabel("Website     :  "));
        west.add(new JLabel("www.example.com"));
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        GridBagConstraints endOfRow = new GridBagConstraints();
        endOfRow.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                JLabel label = new JLabel();
                if (j + 1 < 4) {
                    center.add(label, gbc);
                } else {
                    center.add(label, endOfRow);
                }
                labels.add(label);
            }
        }
        setSize(1000, 300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JLabeleg();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had choose to use GridBagLayout as i can choose the set the gridwidth ^^. Too bad that is I've got not enough reputation to vote your answer. Thanks a lot!!